# Does slim of tensorflow have distributed version?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, distributed-computing, grpc

The [model_deploy](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py) of slim has DeploymentConfig parameters, such as `num_replicas`, `num_ps_tasks`, `worker_job_name`, `ps_job_name`, these terms may appear in distributed version, but I don't think the `model_deploy` is distributed version, because it don't declare `tf.train.ClusterSpec`.

So I can't understand `model_deploy`, does it want to simulate distributed version on stand-alone computer? And on stand-alone computer, what does `ps` and `worker` mean? And the name of `tf.device`, such as `/job:ps/device:CPU:0/task:0`, what hardware are `/job:ps` ans `/task:0` corresponding to ?

Comment: I‘m very confused, so I look forward to help. @mrry

Answer (score 0):

You can call model_deploy in a single-machine and in a distributed setup. If you only have a single machine I recommend setting num_ps_tasks=0 and num_replicas=1 to get the right behavior.

Comment: How to use `model_deploy` in a distributed setup? Is there an example?

Comment: See this:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py
  
In case the link changes:
`models/research/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py`